# How do I prevent errors when clicking an element on the page but not scrolled into view in nightwatch.js?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js, nightwatch

I am writing a test for an element on the page, but not scrolled into view. Whenever I use `pageObject.click("@MyElement)` on the element, it throws this error:

```
Error while running .clickElement() protocol action: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (621, 929)
```

The element will then scroll into view after the error is thrown. Not sure what is happening here.

I have tried using `pageObject.moveToElement("@selector").waitForElementVisible("@selector")`, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

When this happens to me, I usually scroll the **targeted element** into the view first, then proceed to do my actions and/or assertions on it.

We'll use the [execute](https://nightwatchjs.org/api/execute.html) method:

```
browser.element('css selector', <targetElemSelector>, (result) => {
  browser.execute('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({behavior: "instant", block: "center", inline: "center"})', [result.value]);
  browser.click(result.value.ELEMENT);
});
```

This approach also gives you a lot of flexibility with positioning your targeted element via [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)'s attributes: *you can lock the element at the top, the bottom, or center like in the example*. This is especially useful for when you have to avoid overlapping of *marketing popups*, *chatbots*, *GDPR notifications*, etc.

Comment: Just tried this using async/await syntax. It says result is undefined.
`const result = await browser.element('css selector', <targetElemSelector>);`

Comment: @DanielOppenlander, do you have a Babel setup enabling that ES6 `async/await` package behind? Please update your question with the relevant software dependencies (_package.json file_). I don't understand why you don't use what I suggested, without async/await. Is the error thrown in the test feature file, or inside the page object file?

Comment: I got the following errors when running yours: `Error while running .locateSingleElement() protocol action: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified`

`Error while running .executeScript() protocol action: javascript error: arguments[0].scrollIntoView is not a function`

`Error while running .clickElement() protocol action: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (621, 929)`